# Is code required to be digitally signed for Word 2010 and Excel 2010 Addins

Tags: vba, ms-word, code-signing

I have built template-based add ins for Word and Excel version 2003 and previous.  Those versions always required the the code to be digitally signed so that it would run on machines that had macro security turned on.

I am now working on some template based add ins for Office 2010 (to be delivered as a protected .dotm file.  The add ins will create custom ribbons that provide business functionality.  It looks like while I can do code signing, I no longer need to do code signing if I install my .dotm file into [user profile]\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\Startup. Can anyone verify this?  In my limited testing this seems to work and I am interested in distributing this to some computers out of our domain where my code signing certificate is not trusted.

Any help would greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that has been the case since Word 97 to Word 2010 - dot/dotm files in the STARTUP folder are not checked for signing (apparently because getting them into that folder is supposed to be a manual effort). It will work without signing as long as someone has not disabled STARTUP folder add-ins (the KB on how someone would disable it is here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/921541 under section "Disable the Startup folder add-ins").